# Flag a value that occurs twice in a row after ordering

Tags: t-sql, duplicates

I have data consisting of student information, a student GPA category consisting of two categories ('GPA < 2.5'; 'GPA OK'), and the term associated with the GPA. I want to create a flag column that assigns a static value (0) to the flag for rows where GPA Category equals 'GPA OK', another value when GPA Category equals 'GPA < 2.5' (1), *and another value when 'GPA < 2.5' occurs twice in a row after ordering the data by student and term (2)*. See an example of what I want to accomplish below:

```
Student        Term       GPA Category    FLAG
StudentA    Fall   2021     GPA OK         0 -- Flag for when GPA OK occurs
StudentA    Spring 2022     GPA < 2.5      1 -- Flag for when GPA < 2.5 occurs
StudentA    Summer 2022     GPA < 2.5      2 -- Flag for when GPA < 2.5 occurs at least twice in a row
StudentB    Fall   2021     GPA < 2.5      1
StudentB    Summer 2021     GPA < 2.5      2
StudentB    Fall   2021     GPA < 2.5      2
StudentC    Fall   2021     GPA < 2.5      1
StudentC    Summer 2022     GPA < 2.5      2
StudentC    Fall   2022     GPA OK         0
StudentC    Spring 2023     GPA < 2.5      1
StudentC    Summer 2023     GPA OK         0
StudnetC    Fall   2023     GPA OK         0
```

In case it is relevant, the Student, Term, and GPA Category fields are fields that I have calculated in the Select statement using the CONCAT, iif, and CASE function, respectively.
Can anybody help me out here? This one has me stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LAG`, I'm assuming you either have a RowNumber or can generate one to keep these records in the desired order. I would also suggest moving your existing `SELECT` statement to a CTE since you note both the Student and GPA_Category are calculated, that way you can call them in the final `SELECT` as values.

```
    DECLARE @t1 TABLE (RowN INT, Student VARCHAR(50), Term VARCHAR(20), [GPA_Category] VARCHAR(20))
    
    INSERT INTO @t1
    VALUES
    (1,'StudentA',    'Fall   2021',     'GPA OK'),         
    (2,'StudentA',    'Spring 2022',     'GPA < 2.5'),    
    (3,'StudentA',    'Summer 2022',     'GPA < 2.5'),     
    (4,'StudentB',    'Fall   2021',     'GPA < 2.5'),    
    (5,'StudentB',    'Summer 2021',     'GPA < 2.5'),      
    (6,'StudentB',    'Fall   2021',     'GPA < 2.5'),      
    (7,'StudentC',    'Fall   2021',     'GPA < 2.5'),      
    (8,'StudentC',    'Summer 2022',     'GPA < 2.5'),      
    (9,'StudentC',    'Fall   2022',     'GPA OK'),      
    (10,'StudentC',    'Spring 2023',     'GPA < 2.5'),      
    (11,'StudentC',    'Summer 2023',     'GPA OK'),      
    (12,'StudentC',    'Fall   2023',     'GPA OK')
    
    SELECT *,
    CASE WHEN LAG(Student, 1) OVER (ORDER BY RowN) = Student 
             AND LAG(GPA_Category,1) OVER (ORDER BY RowN) LIKE 'GPA < 2.5'
             AND GPA_Category LIKE 'GPA < 2.5' THEN 2
          WHEN GPA_Category LIKE 'GPA < 2.5' THEN 1
          WHEN GPA_Category LIKE 'GPA OK' THEN 0 END AS Flag
    FROM @t1 t
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked. The only thing I don't understand, still, after reading about LAG in Microsoft's documentation is why you put 'GPA OK' in the third argument in the LAG function. If you could illuminate that for me, that would be great. Nevertheless, great answer. This really helped me out.

Comment: On the rows where you are not going to return a viable result, `LAG` will take a default value. Originally I thought we'd need to get past that first `WHEN` on the first row, so I added that 'GPA OK' to make it false, but after further thought it is superfluous. In this `CASE`  usage, `NULL` works just as well. I'll edit those two defaults out.